# .htaccess RewriteCond and condition not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get a series of rewrite conditions working, with the logic being this

```
if condition1 or
(condition2 and condition3) or
..
```

This is what I have in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone" [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android&mobile" [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iemobile" [NC]
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the and operator isn't working as I thought it would.

(as you might guess, the idea is to detect android phones but not tablets)

Is there a way to write that and condition to achieve the results I'm looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `[OR]` flag doesn't work as nice enough for it to be useful, it only works for either all "or"'d or all "and"'d conditions. It's not very predictable. What you may need to do is separate them out to several rules and either use the `S` flag to skip stuff or the pass-through.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
# Prevent rewrite looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if "iphone" OR
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=3]

# "android" AND "mobile", OR
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2]

# "iemobile"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# skip everything, none of the conditions match
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# apply the rule
RewriteRule ^ /do-something [L]
```

Looks like a mess but that's mod_rewrite for you.

The first rule is to prevent any sort of internal rewrite looping. The "# skip everything" rule is the one that gets applied if none of the 3 conditions match, it essentially does nothing excepts stops any rewriting. If you have other rules after all of this stuff that you want to get applied, you can replace the `L` flag with `S=1`.

The last rule is the rule that gets applied if any of the 3 conditions matches.